# Hash a Sequence of positive/negative integers

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashcode

I have a file with millions of lines (actually it's an online stream of data, which means we are receiving it line by line) , each line consists of an array of integers which is not sorted (positive and negative) there's no limit for the each number and the lengths are different and we might have duplicate values in one line,

I want to remove the `duplicate lines` (if 2 lines have same values regardless of how they are ordered we consider them duplicate), is there any good hashing function ?

We want to do this in `O(n)` while `n` is number of lines (we can assume that the maximum possibele number of elements in each line is constant, e.g. we have maximum of 100 elements in each line)

I've read some of the questions posted here in stackoverflow and I also googled it, most of them were for the cases where the arrays are of the same length or the integers are positive or even or they are sorted, is there any way to solve this in general case ?

My solution: 
First we sort each line with the use of `O(n)` sorting algorithm e.g. `Counting sort` , then we put them into a string and then we use `md5` hashing to put them into a hashset. If it's not in the set we put it into that set, if it's already in the list we check the arrays with the same hash value.

Problem with the solution : sorting using the `Counting Sort` takes a lot of space as there's no limit for the numbers and the collisions are possible .

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using a hashing algorithm on a set of data this large is that you have a high probability of two different lines hashing to the same value.  You want to stay in O(n) but I am not sure that is possible, with the size of the data and accuracy needed.  If you use heapsort, which is space efficient and then traverse down the new sorted data removing consecutive lines that are the same you could accomplish this in O(nlogn)

Comment: You mean to heap sort each line ? actually the data is not offline, it's an `online stream` of data, which means that you cannot sort the whole file